# tap on space cause the letters above to be taped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6, keyboard

I have a textField and a delegate view controller
I add only one function to the view controller

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;   // return NO to not change text
{
    return NO;
}
```

than I taped some words...
tap the space rapidly.
than I noticed after a while that one tap the space catch and one tap the letter above my finger catch.
look at the 0:30 seconds video please:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4kV2RER-cU

any idea?

It should be note that it happened me on iOS 6.0 and above
on iPad 2 iPad 3 iPad 4, iPhone 5 and iPod 5.
I also open bug at Apple Bug Reporter. But I will be happy to find a workaround.

Comment: It seems to be more like a problem with your ipad touch screen. Does it happen only with your textfield ?

Comment: it's happend me on iPad 2 iPad 3 iPad 4 iphone 5 and iPod 5